# Schengen visa for two subsequent short trips: One visa or two?

Tags: visas, schengen, thai-citizens

I will go to France from 17/12/13 – 19/12/13, then I will come back to London. And again I will go back to Portugal and Spain from 26/12/13 to 03/01/14 which I will stay in Spain for the longest period. However, the Spanish consulate told me that I have to request for the visa from the French consulate.

The point is:
Do I need to apply for a visa for a single trip two times (from French and Spanish consulate) or a single visa for multiple time (from French consulate).

Comment: The purpose is for tourism and I am Non-UK/EU resident, but studying in UK now

Comment: I am a bit surprised that the Spanish would refuse to examine the request in this scenario but there isn't a lot of time so you should probably contact the French consulate as soon as possible, stressing that the Spanish think you should apply there.

Comment: Actually I have applied the VISA to Spain Consulate, but they said that I will go France first, as a result of this, I have to apply at France Consulate, but I am afraid that when I apply at France's. They will push me to apply at Spain's again !

Comment: I come from Thailand

Answer (score 5):

I would definitely apply for a multiple entry visa from the French embassy, which will be cheaper and less hassle.  If this is your first Schengen visa, you will need to present documentation for both trips to prove that you need multiple entries, since otherwise they will only give you a single entry.  Having a business/educational need to travel with invitation letters from professors etc will also increase the odds of success.

If you are only granted single entry, then it's back to plan B: apply for a second single entry from Spain.

Comment: Thank you, I will apply VISA next week, so wish me luck !