# Can I apply for two Schengen visas if I have two subsequent trips within a short period?

Tags: visas, schengen

I am traveling to Germany on May 1st for an exhibition for which I have already obtained a visa and its validity is up to May 13th. I am returning on May 12th and then traveling on May 17th to UK, and from UK to Switzerland for vacation with family. As time is very short for applying for a Schengen visa again after returning on the 12th with May 13-14 being a Saturday and Sunday, can I apply for Schengen visa again and can I get 2 valid Schengen visa?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21703/schengen-visa-for-two-subsequent-short-trips-one-visa-or-two. Also: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/55729/can-i-get-a-multi-entry-schengen-visa-if-travelling-to-two-different-countries-o?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 4):

> can I apply for Schengen visa again and can I get 2 valid Schengen visa?

Yes.  Your first visa expires before the second trip, so your visas will not have overlapping periods of validity.

Answer (score 0):

> CAN I APPLY FOR SCHENGEN VISA AGAIN AND CAN I GET 2 VALID SCHENGEN VISA?

You cannot have two visas which are **valid on the same date**.

Your visa will expire on 13 April, and so you will need a new visa to travel on 17 April.

Because the new visa will start on 17 April, i.e. **after** the old one has expired, **you can (and should) apply for the new visa now, before going on your first trip to Germany**

Comment: Do you have a reference to support your claim?  I see nothing that prohibits two valid visas if the periods of validity do not overlap.

Comment: You cannot have two Schengens where any of the dates are contemporaneous. As long as the dates are not concurrent, it's fine.

Comment: @GayotFow This is whaty I said

Comment: You wrote "You cannot have two visas valid on the same date.", which isn't right. A visa which starts at some point in the future is still valid because it has not been cancelled or revoked. I have not yet voted on this, If you correct it, please ping me.

Comment: @GayotFow So you mean if visa A is valid 14 April-14 May and Visa B 1 May-1 June (overlapping 1-14 May), is that a possible Scenario?

Comment: No that wouldn't be a good scenario

Comment: @GayotFow Which is **exactly** what I point out in my answer ("cannot be valid on the same date")

Comment: @GayotFow, Crazydre but the first visa is valid until May 12 and the second trip begins on May 17th, with travel to Switzerland sometime thereafter.  So it seems that the answer to the question is "yes."

Comment: "Your visa is valid for both your trip to Germany and to Switzerland; thus no new visa is needed": this is incorrect.  The first visa expires on 13 May, and the trip to Switzerland is planned for some time after 17 May.

Comment: @phoog Didn't read carefully enough; edited