# Two Schengen visas for the same period

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, france, standard-visitor-visas

I am residing in UK (with Indian passport and BRP) and had recently applied for German Schengen visa for tourism purpose (Type C) which clearly mentions Besuch (visit visa) on it. I got that visa for 8 months validity.
Now, I have to also travel to France in  August for which my company and I decided to apply for a Schengen business visa from the French embassy. I had all invitation letters, business letters, salary slips, etc. Today I received my passport back without any French Schengen visa stamped and no email or paper inside explaining rejection or not providing business visa.
But for a strange reason, the passport was sent to my address in the envelope with passport open on page where German Schengen visa exists. I do not know whether the French embassy wanted to indicate that I cannot apply for another Schengen visa if the previous one is still active.

If yes, then I do not understand how I can use the German Schengen visa that I applied for my tourism to go to my workplace in France for attending some business meetings. Even if border control allows, it is against the company compliance and also on the German Schengen visa is clearly mentioned Type C but in remarks is mentioned BESUCHVISUM (visit visa).

Please guide about any law that states that a person cannot hold an active Schengen visa from 2 countries at the same time of same type?

Thanks.

---

I have multiple entry visa for Germany and I will use German visa before I wanted to go to France. My German personal trip begins in end of July 2023 and then after having couple of weeks of trip, I wanted to go to France for business trip, but it seems the embassy didn't want to give me any visa. Now I do not know if I can use the German visit visa for a business reason in France.

Comment: Will you use the visa issued by Germany before you need to go to France? Is it a multiple entry visa?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/91800/can-i-apply-for-two-schengen-visas-if-i-have-two-subsequent-trips-within-a-short

Answer (score 2):

Schengen visas are not issued for a specific purpose.  The application asks you to declare the purpose of the trip for which you are applying, but if you are granted a multiple-entry visa, you can use it for other trips for other purposes.

> I do not know whether French Embassy wanted to indicate that I cannot apply for another Schengen visa if the previous one is still active.

Yes, that is precisely what the French embassy wanted to indicate.

> If yes, then I do not understand how I can use the German Schengen visa that I applied for my tourism to go to my workplace in France for attending some business meetings. Even if border control allows, it is against the company compliance and also on the German Schengen visa is clearly mentioned Type C but in remarks is mentioned BESUCHVISUM (visit visa).

A business visit is also a kind of visit.  What do you mean by "company compliance"?

> Please guide about any law that states that a person cannot hold an active Schengen visa from 2 countries at the same time of same type?

I just scanned the [Schengen Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02009R0810-20200202) and the [VIS regulation](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/ALL/?uri=CELEX%3A32008R0767), and I didn't see anything saying this explicitly, but it is certainly implicit in the nature of the Schengen visa system itself.  For example, recital 8 of the [2009 version of the code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32009R0810) calls for issuing multiple-entry visas where possible to reduce the administrative burden for consulates and increase convenience for travelers:

> (8) Provided that certain conditions are fulfilled, multiple-entry visas should be issued in order to lessen the administrative burden of Member States’ consulates and to facilitate smooth travel for frequent or regular travellers. ...